# Extract poll results from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to extract the data of a given Facebook Question/Poll that is inside a group?

It does not need to be automatized. There is a single poll result that I want to manually retrieve the answers and analyze them.

I thought of using the Question GET, but is was deprecated in v1.0, as shown here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/question

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's currently no way you can do this via the Graph API.