# Facebook poll based on images

Tags: facebook-graph-api, voting, vote

I wish to submit couple of images to Facebook using my app and invite my friends to vote on it for a specific time interval. My question is -

1. Does graphAPI support this.
2. Can I integrate this with my backend system so that I can get the count of likes/dislikes against each image.

Would appreciate support on this.

Answer (score 1):

Previous solution is deprecated and I couldn't find anything for new version of Graph API in their document.
Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30342920/811922), apparently, there is no way to do this. At least at current time.